# Passing variable to method from another controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am developing a Laravel 8 application, and I need to create XML files with data from the database.
So I first created the controller and method to generate the XML file and tested it to work correctly.
Now I need to call the `exportXML` method of the `ExportFileController` inside the `PrenotazioneSpedizioneController` controller.
Reading the Laravel documentation and here on Stack I saw that you can call the method like this `\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML');`.

I tested it without parameters, and it works as expected.
The problem I have now is the following, is it possible to pass a parameter to the `exportXML` method which I call with:

`\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML');`?

I was thinking something like `\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML')->with('racc', $racc);`.

I appreciate any suggestions or advice.

- PrenotazioneSpedizioneController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\CodiciPrenotazione;
use App\Models\Raccomandata;
use App\Models\Prenotazioni;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class PrenotazioniSpedizioniController extends Controller
{

    // dashboard delle prenotazioni
    public function index()
    {
        $page_title = 'Resoconto prenotazioni';
        $page_description = 'Pagina di resoconto delle prenotazioni effettuate';
        $logo = config('dz.public.logo');
        $logoText = config('dz.public.logo_text');
        $active = "active";
        $action = 'dashboard_4';

        $total = CodiciPrenotazione::count();
        
        $free = CodiciPrenotazione::where('stato', 0)->count();

        $codici = CodiciPrenotazione::select('*')->get()->toArray();

        return view('prenotazioni.dashboard', compact('page_title', 'page_description', 'logo', 'logoText', 'active', 'action'))
        ->with('total', $total)
        ->with('free', $free)
        ->with('codici', $codici);
    }

    // GESTIONE DELLE SPEDIZIONI
    public function gestisciSpedizione(Request $request){
       
        try{

            set_time_limit(-1);

            //devo recuperare le raccomandate dal DB con isGenerated = 0 e per data e lotto

            //prendo la data odierna, devo spedire quelle con data precedente.
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            //recupero le raccomandate
            $racc = Raccomandata::select('*')
            ->where([
                ['isGenerated', '=', '0'], //non generate
                ['created_at', '>', $date.' 00:00:00'], //la data di creazione deve essere precedente la data odierna
                ['idCliente', '=', '1'], //selezioniamo le raccomandate solo per il cliente
            ])
            ->get();
            //raggruppiamo per idCommessa e cronologico
            $racc = $racc->groupBy(['idCommessa', 'cronologico'])->toArray();
            

            //passo alla creazione dei file
            //richiamo la procedura per generare i file .xml
            return \App::call('App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController@exportXML'); // here i want pass $racc variable.





            //loggiamo l'evento e redirectiamo con il messaggio di success dell'operazione
            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('L\'utente '.Auth::user().' ha prenotato con successo la spedizione numero: '.$request->input('codice_prenotazione').' FILE :');

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Prenotazione della spedizione effettuata con successo');

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('L\'utente '.Auth::user().' non è riuscito a prenotare la spedizione COD:'.$request->input('codice_prenotazione').' ERRORE:'.$e);

            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Non è stato possibile prenotare la spedizione numero: '.$request->input('codice_prenotazione'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not refactor your code, such that the controller itself solely uses another services that generates such data? This also helps to make your code reusable and testable, as generating an XML file and serving it as a response do not need to be connecte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call controllers inside another controllers.

You are facing this problem because you are putting business logic inside your controllers (and it is a well known bad practice).

The solution is to use another class, called a service class, where you put the logic. You then call this class where you need to (in your case, in `PrenotazioniSpedizioniController` and `ExportFileController`).

This is a quick example:

Create the file `app\Services\ExportService.php`:

```php
class ExportService {
    public function exportXML($arguments)
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

Then, in your controllers:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController;

class PrenotazioniSpedizioniController extends Controller
{
     public function yourMethod(Request $request){
         app(ExportService::class)->exportXML($arguments);
     }
}
```

This way you keep clean controllers and have a more testable code.

*Keep in mind this is a minimal example to solve your problem and I can only advise you to dig further on project architecture and design patterns.*

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  keep clean controllers and have a more testable code

Comment: Thanks i've really appreciate your help!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call controllers inside another controllers.

You are facing this problem because you are putting business logic inside your controllers (and it is a well known bad practice).

The solution is to use another class, called a service class, where you put the logic. You then call this class where you need to (in your case, in PrenotazioniSpedizioniController and ExportFileController).

This is a quick example:

```html
You should not call controllers inside another controllers.

You are facing this problem because you are putting business logic inside your controllers (and it is a well known bad practice).

The solution is to use another class, called a service class, where you put the logic. You then call this class where you need to (in your case, in PrenotazioniSpedizioniController and ExportFileController).

This is a quick example:

Create the file app\Services\ExportService.php:

class ExportService {
    public function exportXML($arguments)
    {
        //something
    }
}
Then, in your controllers:

use App\Http\Controllers\ExportFileController;

class PrenotazioniSpedizioniController extends Controller
{
     public function yourMethod(Request $request){
         app(ExportService::class)->exportXML($arguments);
     }
}
This way you keep clean controllers and have a more testable code.

Keep in mind this is a minimal example to solve your problem and I can only advise you to dig further on project architecture and design patterns.
```

This way you keep clean controllers and have a more testable code.

Keep in mind this is a minimal example to solve your problem and I can only advise you to dig further on project architecture and design patterns.